# Lift of isometries of spherical space forms

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-geometry

If we have an isometry between two spherical space forms, then it is said that it lifts to an isometry of the sphere. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

I'll be assuming your spheres are at least two dimensional.  (If they are one dimensional, it's tautologically true because sphereical space forms of 1 dimension are just circles themselves).

Call the two spherical space forms $X$ and $Y$.  Then we have universal covering maps (which are local isometries) $\pi_1:S^n\rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2:S^n\rightarrow Y$.

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an isometry.  Consider the map $S^n\rightarrow Y$ given by $f\circ \pi_1$.  Since $S^n$ is simply connected, this induces the $0$ map on fundamental groups.  By the universal lifting property of covering maps, there is a function $g:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ with $f\circ \pi_1 = \pi_2 \circ g$.  I claim that $g$ is an isometry.

First, to see $g$ is a diffeomorphism, use the same argument on $f^{-1} \circ \pi_2$ to get a map $h:S^n\rightarrow S^n$.  By fiddling with basepoints a bit, one can then show that $h = g^{-1}$.  Thus, $g$ is a diffeomorphism.

Now, since $f$, $\pi_1$, and $\pi_2$ are all local isometries, on any neighborhood where $\pi_2$ is $1-1$, we have $g^\ast =  \pi_1^\ast f^\ast (\pi_2^{\ast})^{-1}$, so is a composition of metric preserving maps, so it preserves the metric as well.